# Applying a projector to a qubit in a qiskit circuit

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, error-correction

I'd like to be able to apply $|0 \rangle \langle 0|$ to project a qubit to the state $|0 \rangle$ in the middle of qiskit circuit (see, for example, the attached circuit).

[image]

I wonder if, in general, one can customize those orange boxes in some way and if that works in the real hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *hope* this is what you are looking for.

---

Within IBM hardware, there is a new option called "reset" that allows you to reset a certain qubit back to the state $|0\rangle$. For instance,

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
qreg_q = QuantumRegister(3, 'q')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(3, 'c')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q, creg_c)
circuit.x(qreg_q[0])
circuit.h(qreg_q[2])
circuit.cswap(qreg_q[2], qreg_q[0], qreg_q[1])
circuit.h(qreg_q[2])
circuit.reset(qreg_q[1])
```

[image]

Within the circuit composer, you can find the reset method as well with the $|0\rangle$ symbol:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!. Is it possible to customize operators in the middle of the circuits? what about if instead I want to get $| 1 \rangle$ ?

Comment: I believe you can only reset it to the state $|0\rangle$. To get $|1\rangle$ you would have to apply the $X$ gate after the reset.

Comment: Oh, you're right, applying $X$. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem!!! :)